# Passing multi parameter to Td inline JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Passing one parameter (report.id) to removeUser function works fine, but when I want to pass two parameter (report.id and report.name) I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

I tried '(" +report.id +","+ report.name +")'

I tried '(" +report.id report.name +")'

but none works, what I am doing wrong here

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "xxx",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    var html = '';
                    $.each(result, function (key, report) {
                        html += '<tr>';
                        html += '<td>' + report.id + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + report.name + '</td>';
                        html += "<td><a onClick='removeUser(" +report.id + report.name +")'" + "'> Remove </a></td>";
                        html += '</tr>';
                    });
                    $('#users').html(html);
                },


        function removeUser(id, name) {
            alert("ID: "+ id + "Name: "+ name)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need commas between the parameters, and you need quotes only around `report.name`.

It's much easier to write this using a template literal rather than concatenation.

```
html += `<td><a href="#" onClick='removeUser(${report.id}, "${report.name}")'> Remove </a></td>`;
```

Also, since you're doing this with an `a` element, you should set its `href` so it doesn't try to link to another page after running the `onclick` function.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfect